# Show that $W(t)$ is almost surely non-differentiable at $t=0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Show that $W_t$ is almost surely non-differentiable at $t=0$. Of course, $W(t)$ denotes a standard Wiener process.

It is enough to show that

$$P(\{\omega : \exists  \epsilon>0 \: \forall \delta >0 \:\exists t<\delta :\frac{|W_t(\omega)|}{|t|} >\epsilon\})=1 \mbox{.}$$

Any hint please?

Comment: Why not have a look at the literature? Any reasonable book on this topic contains either a proof of the statement or at least a reference to a proof. I don't see any sense in copying the proof from a book. Alternatively, you may have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/957783/36150).

Comment: @saz I just thought it is some elemetary proof that I would be able to complete after receving some hint. But apparently it's not trivial at all...

Comment: Well, no, it's not trivial. However, the proof in the linked question looks somewhat more complicated/lentghy because of the comments/questions.  For example the proof in René Schillings book on Brownian motion is 1 page and, in my opinion, very readable. But again: Please have a look at the literature (or the web) and add some thoughts on the problem to your question.